# Is dying your hair allowed for a 12 year old?

Tags: salat, hair

I'm a 12 year old Muslim, and I want to know if dying my hair is allowed?  And can I pray if I dye my hair?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are a girl.

No there is no mention of it being as Haraam. If a girl likes to look great it's totally OK and natural. The only thing is that the this beautifying should only been seen by those who are Mahram.

I know that Many Muslim parents tell their young daughters that you can't put on makeup and stuff. It's correct if she's going out to where there are non-mahrams. If she's doing it where all people are her mahrams then it's really forcing your daughter into something Islam itself doesn't force. Usually these daughters will change radically when they move away from their parents.

Comment: It is a helpful point as you mentioned regarding being in front of mahram/non-mahram. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score -1):

If you parents allow you to dye your hair, then you can. The Prophet and some of his closest companions dyed  their hair but you can only do it if it doesn't imitate kafir women. For more information, you can go on these websites:
http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/4461
https://islamqa.info/en/82103